# Having trouble with item layout for a side drawer nav

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with formatting the layout of items in my side drawer nav.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ahudson609/pen/NWepwvo)

Basically, i want the main menu parent item element to have the styles (Dashboard, Customers, Schedule) as it does now, but i want the icons and text to align for all menu items. I'm having trouble explaining this.

[image: The actual output]

I want each "item" to be the same height, and the outer "item" element needs to be horizontally centered like it now, except, the interior contents, both icons and text, need to align perfectly with all other menu items.

One other issue im having is that i want the  ending of the sub menu to be the same as parent while keeping the indent.

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ac9c0a0f2b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sideDrawer">
        <div class="sideDrawerHeader">
            <div class="companyNameContainer">
                <span class="companyName">Business, LLC.</span>

                <div class="toggleContainer">
                    <span class="toggleIconSpan">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: white;"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="sidebar">


                <li class="nav-item parent">
                    <a class="nav-link has-submenu" href="#">
                        <div class="navHeader">
                            <i class="fa-light fa-desktop fa-lg icon"></i><br>
                            <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>





                <li class="nav-item parent">
                    <a class="nav-link has-submenu" href="#">
                        <div class="navHeader">
                            <i class="fa-light fa-users fa-lg icon"></i><br>
                            <span>Customers</span>
                        </div>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-sm icon chevron"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="nav-link-child">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <div class="navHeader">
                                    <i class="fa-light fa-users fa-lg icon"></i><br>
                                    <span>Customers</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link-child">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <div class="navHeader">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-house fa-lg icon"></i><br>
                                    <span>Properties</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item parent">
                    <a class="nav-link has-submenu" href="#">
                        <div class="navHeader">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days fa-lg icon"></i><br>
                            <span>Schedule</span>
                        </div>
                        <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-sm icon chevron"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="nav-link-child">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <div class="navHeader">
                                    <i class="fa-light fa-users fa-lg icon"></i><br>
                                    <span>Customers</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-link-child">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <div class="navHeader">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-house fa-lg icon"></i><br>
                                    <span>Properties</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    

</body>

</html>
```